# How to submit a Form without using Submit event on Button.

Tags: php, html

I've made a simple calendar where you can select year and month through a dropdown list.

```
<form name=calenderselect method='post' action='calendar.php'>
<select name='month' id='month'>
<option>January</option>
<option>Februari</option>
<option>March</option>
....
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change' />
</form>
```

I find it abit annoying that you have to press the submit button every time you want to change month. I would like it to change the moment I click the month in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a client-side event to achieve this (maybe "onChanged" for the select?)

1.listen for the event: add `onChange="submitForm()` to the select tag
2.define the `submitForm()` javascript function. It will basically be a simple form submit, nothing too long

done!

Look in google: "how to submit form through Javascript":

Answer (score 7):

here you are: `<select name='month' id='month' onclick="this.form.submit()">`

but i guess you really want to submit the form by `onchange` event.

Comment: what if it has more than one form?

Comment: **it**? `this` specifies the `select` element

Answer (score 3):

Add a javascript event on your select :

```
<select name="month" id="month" onChange="yourjsfunction()">
```

Comment: And in the function you can write the selection of the select in another form element

Comment: and, if you like it to submit (like the question title implies), you can do document.forms['calenderselect'].submit() within the js function

Comment: Yup missread the title but I thought he wanted to make a little calendar element or something :)

Comment: Tried it with JS as many sugested but unfortunally it does nothing. No error message or anything. Nothing happens at all when i click another month. I still need to klick the button.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make any mistake writing the js code? Because when there's an error the script just don't launch at all (Happened a lot to me :p)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="month" id="month" onChange="document.getElementsByName('calenderselect')[0].submit()">
```

Comment: what if it has more than one form, or this one isn't the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Given we can use JavaScript for this functionality (as mentioned in other answers), one has to wonder if we need submit at all for a change in a date control. Using AJAX to get back the required data for the selected date would be smoother as it would feature no page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery..

```
$("#month").live('change',function() {
  $('form').submit();
});
```

this is useful if you want your html code clean.

Comment: if using jQuery use the jQuery calendar, its cute.